# C-Interface for interactive bash

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am searching for a C interface for bash shells. I.e. I would like to have a set of functions which allow me to open a session, execute commands, return the output (STDOUT,STDERR) and finally to close the shell. It could be a library or C source code based on standard libraries.

Comment: I am not aware of any such interface. What is your use case? Anything where the set of commands isn't known in advance would probably turn out to be an ugly brittle hack.

Comment: @highsciguy seems to be looking for some [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) like C library.

Comment: Why?  Anyway, simplest way (to get a persistent environment) would be to write out a shell script to a file then execute it using `system`.  OK, a pipe would be faster, but you can't need fast otherwise you would not be using a shell at all.

Comment: This is a nice question and makes a lot of sense. `system(3)` will not cut it unless there is just a need to run isolated shell commands without regards of the output (either via `stdout` and `stderr` or environment variable manipulations etc).

Comment: The reason for the question is that I want to write my own interactive terminal. One which uses vim. Existing vim based terminals are not useful though because I want to integrate it with an other interactive terminal I have written for a different script language. The basic principle is that vim pipes lines into a C-program which returns the results using a second pipe to vim. I will look through your replies later.

Answer (score 1):

The general root problem seems to be *how to programmatically run interactive terminal program*.

Now this would in my part require actual testing, but you would roughly need to

1. create three [pipes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pipe.7.html) corresponding to child process `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` (the parent process writing to `stdin_pipe` and reading `stdout_pipe` and `stderr_pipe`) using [`pipe(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/pipe.2.html) system call;
2. [fork](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/fork.2.html) and in the child [close](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html) redirect the standard in, out and error to the proper ends of the above pipes by calling [`dup2(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/dup2.2.html);
3. exec ([`execve(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/execve.2.html) / [`execv(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/execv.3.html)) your interactive shell;
4. start [writing](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/write.2.html) commands to `stdin_pipe` and [reading](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/read.2.html) the errors and responses from the other two pipes.

(If you do not need to make the distinction between `stdout` and `stderr` you could just simplify your life by using [`popen(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/popen.3.html) - you could probably redirect `stderr` to `stdout` by proper choice of command string).

For properly working solution, however, I believe you probably would need to use pseudo ttys ([`pty(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/pty.7.html)) by calling [`forkpty(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/forkpty.3.html) instead of just fork.

As it starts to get more and more complicated to take into account all the nyances of dealing with pseudo terminals, why not search for C expect library which should be able to do all this for you. Or emulate how [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net) or some other language equivalent like [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect) is implemented. Actually `expect` seems to provide a C library called [`libexpect(3)`](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.4/expect/libexpect.3.html) for you so that you do not need to write tcl/tk for programming the interaction. I am not personally familiar with the library, and there could be other better ones.

Comment: You'd need to use ptys, almost certainly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - for more complicated scenarios yes, for sure. For example if the programs to run with shell require information about the terminal (like number of columns for `ls`). I think simple shell commands could perhaps still be run with trivial `popen(3)` + `pclose(3)` based approach (setting environment variables, running programs which do not care about terminals). In principle, I cannot see why shells like bash should not allow using them interactively without tty (although they certainly check whether you are running them using tty and adjust behavior accordingly).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to achieve something like this:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
      char a[1000];
      gets(a);
      system(a);
      return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
./a.out
cat testing.c
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a[1000];
  gets(a);
  system(a);
  return 0;
}
```

`gets()` and `system` call can get inside a loop.

Comment: Sure, but this will not have persistent environment. Most likely that is what OP is concerned about.

Comment: Yes. For instance all the shell variables should be preserved between subsequent commands.